# Sphinx search sql_attr_multi - where condition

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I need to set an index.

sql_attr_multi = uint categories from query; SELECT item_id, category_id FROM connections WHERE value=2

It works fine If I set the value static.

That value is a variable so I want to assign it through a filter but it doesn`t work because I want to filter "sql_attr_multi" not the $sql.

$cl->setFilter("value", array(2));

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

setFilter has to do only with searching ( searchd process ). It's a filter applied to an attribute. 
The categories sql_attr_multi attribute values can't be changed depending on a condition ( unless you reindex or use updateAttributes).
If values doesn't vary much , create for each one a mva attribute.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking on that, but it should be the last soution :)

Comment: Maybe updateAttributes is a solution. But I want to add a condition into an existing attr.

Comment: That wouldn't work. It depends what will need there. Do you need to search for a specific category and value, do you need sorting,grouping on category/value as well ? You could create a sql_joined_field instead of multi and combine category id with value ( something like 100_2 ) and you will have for an item_id something like '100_2 101_3 102_2 etc' .This will allow you to make a search on category_id and value. You could also  keep the categories multi attribute to use it for grouping.

Comment: which one? can you explain a bit better?

Comment: I`m using mva for the side menu categories (nr items). An item could be in multiple categories. cat 1 (20), cat 2 (10) etc. It works fine but i need to append a condition to sql_attr_multi categories. Maybe is a way to pass the variable through api?

Comment: I need it dinamicaly...I can`t define sql_attr_multi categories for each value.