# Sphinx Search - Where condition for attributes

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

```
sql_attr_multi = uint categories from query; SELECT item_id, category_id FROM items_categories WHERE value=2
```

How could I proceed to **pass the value** variable through the **sphinxapi**? I need it to **filter** the **attr** and I **can`t use setFilter**.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you started a new question? This seems to just be a continuation of your previous question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271656/sphinx-search-sql-attr-multi-where-condition

Comment: Yes, I should edit the old question instead...